# Swagger UI does not show all header values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have Spring Boot REST controller with header which can have more than 1 value:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/example", headers = {"version=v1", "version=v2"})
@Api(value = "Example API")
public class ExampleController {
```

And using Springfox implementation of the Swagger. When I load Swagger UI, I can see and select only v1 option from the list for version header. How to show all header values to select in Swagger UI? How to change default header value in Swagger UI list?

Comment: Look into this link, it may be useful. https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2018/02/19/versioning-rest-api-with-spring-boot-and-swagger/

Comment: It doesn't have solution for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used ApiImplicitParams on controller methods:

```
@ApiImplicitParams({
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "version", allowableValues="v1,v2", required = false, dataType = "String", paramType = "header")
})
```

With [allowableValues](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.X/apidocs/index.html?io/swagger/annotations/ApiImplicitParams.html):

> 1. To set a list of values, provide a comma-separated list. For example: first, second, third.
> 2. To set a range of values, start the value with "range", and surrounding by square brackets include the minimum and maximum values,
>      or round brackets for exclusive minimum and maximum values. For
>      example: range[1, 5], range(1, 5), range[1, 5).
> 3. To set a minimum/maximum value, use the same format for range but use "infinity" or "-infinity" as the second value. For example,
>      range[1, infinity] means the minimum allowable value of this parameter
>      is 1.